# Zend controller exception

Tags: exception, zend-framework

I was requesting a page by submitting a form and sending the data to controller action . But it throws me the following error :

> ```
> Internal error:
> Permission denied.#0 /usr/local/psa/admin/externals/Zend/Controller/Plugin/Broker.php(309):
> ```
>
> Plesk\Application\Controller\Plugin\ForgeryProtection->preDispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http))
>
> ## 1 /usr/local/psa/admin/externals/Zend/Controller/Front.php(941): Zend_Controller_Plugin_Broker->preDispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http))
>
> ## 2 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/pm/Application.php(99): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch() #3
>
> /usr/local/psa/admin/htdocs/modules/rbl2/index.php(6):
> pm_Application->run() #4 {main}

What may be the issue ? Any help is appreciated .

Comment: have you check the permission of target controller-action

Comment: How to check that ? Its working for other actions but not working for this particular action

Comment: is [this](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000733394-Permission-denied-error-in-Plesk-Onyx-while-working-with-databases) your error? :)